# symbols in js file are not recognized in browser cache

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a js file which contains the below text in one of its line

```
 "St_Johns": {
                "exemplarCity": "St. JohnyX92s"
 }
```

i have invoked the getScriptFile() in service by using the ajax call and it returns the stream of bytes which is stored in the browser cache

_

```
getScriptFile: function (fileName) {
            var that = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: this.serviceUrl() + "/GetScript",
                data: { fileName: fileName},
                dataType: "script",
                cache: true,
                error: function () {
                    that._errorMsgPopup(that.locale.utils.FileDownloadError + culture, true);
                }
            });
```

In Service

```
public Stream GetScript(string fileName)
        {
                if (File.Exists(filePath + fileName))
                {
                    stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fileName));
                }

            return stream;
        }
```

Now the problem is some of the symbols in my js files are treated as '�' in browser cache. like the below

```
"St_Johns": {
                "exemplarCity": "St. John�s"
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue. i have tired UTF-8 encoding also.

TIA